# Customizing a toolstrip in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I have a requirement to implement a toolbar similar to microsoft word 2007 using C#.

Actualy I need not implement ribbon control. I just have to implement a similar toolbar that is shown when we click on the tab of the ribbon. Just like grouping some common buttons/controls together (some buttons arranged in horizontal and some in vertical)

How can we do it ?

Comment: You don't want to use a ribbon control, but what you are describing is...a ribbon control.

Comment: I just have to implement ribbob bar . No need to implement ribbon control. How is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest to use a RibbonControl. It does everything you want.
There are many free and commercial RibbonControls available for Windows Forms and WPF.

For example:

- http://ribbon.codeplex.com/
- http://fluent.codeplex.com/
- http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/ribbon-control.aspx
- http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/ribbonbar.aspx

Comment: Can't we implement it without using any thirdparty tool ?

Comment: You can do it, sure. But thats much work to get the real ribbon feeling right. Why not use a open source component that is used by many people? Its free and has no / less bugs.

Comment: I want to implement by myself. Can somebody give me a basic idea to implement it ?

Comment: Go and download one of the open source ribbons and have a look at the source code.